# podspec source and source_files is not taking the local path

Tags: frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

```
[!] Failed to load 'MyFramework' podspec:
[!] Invalid MyFramework.podspec file: undefined method `scource_files=' for #<Pod::Specification name="MyFramework">
Did you mean? source_files=.

from /Users/sunil/workspace/karTesting/MyFramework/MyFramework.podspec:12
-------------------------------------------
s.source = {:path => "Users/sunil/workspace/karTesting/MyFramework"}
s.scource_files = "Users/sunil/workspace/karTesting/**/*.swift"

end
```

--
is it compulsory to host the framework in github cant we host locally .

Comment: `s.scource_files`, you wrote `s.scource_files` with an extra "c" (s**C**ource), not `s.source_files` that's what is saying the error because you mistyped and it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: i realised after posting it . but pod gets installed non of the swift files are copied in the project

Comment: I'd make the path relative to where is the pod spec. And are you sure about the path? What's your file hierarchy?

Comment: it solved after making the path relative. thank you